# Show discord guild id and a guild name when startup

Tags: discord.js

I wan't to ask if it is possible to list all discord guild ids and names that my bot is in when its loading..?

`I need to check if there are any ghost servers..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it possible you can use this:

```js
client.guilds.cache.map(r => `${r.name} - ${r.id}`);
```

Full example:

```js
//Define client and discord
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = New Discord.Client();

//When the client is ready, print all guilds
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(client.guilds.cache.map(r => `${r.name} - ${r.id}`));
});

//Login the client
client.log('your-secret-token');
```

Comment: Hey, iDrunK.

I want to ask if its possible to also log the owner id. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```js
let ids = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id).join(", ");
let names = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.name).join(", ");
console.log(`IDs: ${ids}`);
console.log(`Names: ${names}`);
```

Do this in your `ready` event. You could also join `\n`, then every ID and every name get seperated by new lines.

Or if you want the server name and the server ID next to each other you could do:

```js
let guilds = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => `${guild.name} | ${guild.id}\n`).join("");
console.log(guilds.toString())
```